# Two different methods in selecting teams.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can two sports teams consisting of $11$ members each be formed by $23$ players?

**MY WORK:**

I tried to choose at first $11$ members from  $23$ and then again select $11$ from remaining $12$ of them.  So I get :
$$\binom{23}{11} \times \binom{12}{11}$$
$$=16224936$$

But again,  I can do the division of $23$ players into two groups like -
$$\binom{23}{22}\times \frac{22!}{2!(11!)^2}$$
$$=8112468$$
Which is half of the previous.... I know that the later one is correct, but where do I go wrong in doing the first one?

Comment: Method one selects 11 players for the "home team" and 11 for the "visitors."  Method two removes the distinction of which team is which.

Comment: @DougM...  So which one is appropriate  to use?

Comment: The second method should be used unless the teams are labeled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to find the number of ordered pairs (2-tuples) of team, then you may use the first method.

If you are asked to find the number of unordered pairs (2-element sets) of teams, then you may use the second method.

Note that the first number equals to the double second one because two teams of a pair can`t be equal. This means that each set $\{\,t_1, t_2\,\}$ corresponds to exactly two 2-tuples $(t_1, t_2)$ and $(t_2, t_1)$.